# Black screen using DirectShow SDK on PS3eye usb camera

Tags: camera, directshow

I just figured out the problem that DirectShow cannot detect PS3eye camera when another problem comes to me. 
It was tested that the PS3eye camera can be read by AMcap and by OpenCV using constructor `VideoCapture cap(1)`. When I tried to use function QueryFrame() to grab frames from camera and show it in computer, it returned me a black screen. The codes are as following:

```
IplImage* CCameraDS::QueryFrame()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    if (!m_IsOpen)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    long evCode;
    long size = 0;
    hr = m_pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&m_pMediaControl);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = m_pMediaControl->Run();
        if (FAILED(hr))
            m_pMediaControl->Stop();
        m_pMediaControl->Release();
    }
    else {
        printf("Cannot preview graph.\n");
        return false;
    }

    m_pMediaEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);
    m_pSampleGrabber->GetCurrentBuffer(&size, NULL);

    //if the buffer size changed
    if (size != m_nBufferSize)
    {
        if (m_pFrame)
            cvReleaseImage(&m_pFrame);
        m_nBufferSize = size;
        m_pFrame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(m_nWidth, m_nHeight), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    }
    if (m_pFrame->imageData == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    hr = m_pSampleGrabber->GetCurrentBuffer(&m_nBufferSize, (long*)m_pFrame->imageData);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return NULL;
    cvFlip(m_pFrame);
    return m_pFrame;
}
```

What's the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: You might be asking for a frame before it is actually available (too early). Also the code lacks error checking.

Comment: @RomanR. Thank you for your response. In fact, I have tested this code on the webcam of my laptop and it works well. And I don't really understand what means "too early"? Thanks.